# Oozie workflow in SUSPENDED state on EMR

Tags: oozie, emr

When running a Oozie bundle, we are seeing some workflows getting into SUSPENDED state. The job actually succeeds but Oozie puts the workflow in SUSPENDED state and the job never completes. This happens only on few workflows and others succeed.

Oozie Error:

```
JA009   JA009: Failed to load class: [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl]       
Back


Detailed log:
2016-09-22 09:15:35,674  WARN PigActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[ip-10-39-155-120.ec2.internal] USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sourceCustomerDimGlobal-wf] JOB[0000066-160921113823531-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000066-160921113823531-oozie-oozi-W@Pig-scdGlobalTransformation] Exception in check(). Message[Failed to load class: [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl]]
java.io.IOException: Failed to load class: [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl]
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobStatus(ClientServiceDelegate.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobStatus(YARNRunner.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getJob(Cluster.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:591)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getJobUsingCluster(JobClient.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getJobInner(JobClient.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getJob(JobClient.java:631)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.getRunningJob(JavaActionExecutor.java:1333)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.check(JavaActionExecutor.java:1356)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionCheckXCommand.execute(ActionCheckXCommand.java:182)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionCheckXCommand.execute(ActionCheckXCommand.java:56)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-09-22 09:15:35,675  WARN ActionCheckXCommand:523 - SERVER[ip-10-39-155-120.ec2.internal] USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sourceCustomerDimGlobal-wf] JOB[0000066-160921113823531-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000066-160921113823531-oozie-oozi-W@Pig-scdGlobalTransformation] Exception while executing check(). Error Code [JA009], Message[JA009: Failed to load class: [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl]]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA009: Failed to load class: [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl]
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:456)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:440)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.check(JavaActionExecutor.java:1456)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionCheckXCommand.execute(ActionCheckXCommand.java:182)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionCheckXCommand.execute(ActionCheckXCommand.java:56)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to load class: [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl]
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobStatus(ClientServiceDelegate.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobStatus(YARNRunner.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getJob(Cluster.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:591)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getJobUsingCluster(JobClient.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getJobInner(JobClient.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getJob(JobClient.java:631)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.getRunningJob(JavaActionExecutor.java:1333)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.check(JavaActionExecutor.java:1356)
    ... 9 more
```